# Pip installing from github installs only __init__.py file

Tags: python, git, github, pip

I'm trying to grasp the git(hub) way of managing software. I have a repository:
https://github.com/pythonishvili/django-inguri

And I try to pip install it with this command

```
pip install git+git://github.com/pythonishvili/django-inguri.git
```

The response I get:

```
Downloading/unpacking git+git://github.com/pythonishvili/django-inguri.git
  Cloning git://github.com/pythonishvili/django-inguri.git to /tmp/pip-bv5r89-build
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from git+git://github.com/pythonishvili/django-inguri.git

Installing collected packages: inguri
  Running setup.py install for inguri

Successfully installed inguri
Cleaning up...
```

But installation went clearly wrong because all I get in my virtualenv (`/home/username/.virtualenvs/envname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/inguri`) are two files:

```
__init__.py
__init__.pyc
```

What did I do wrong? How do I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to add all the subdirectories of your project to the `packages` option of your `setup.py` file. Right now, you have just the outermost directory - `inguri`. You would need to add `inguri.ads`, `inguri.ads.migrations` and so forth (as they contain `.py` files too which you want to include in your distribution).

You also need to add the following line in your manifest file: `recursive-include inguri *`

Comment: Thanks, turns out that `recursive-include inguri *` is enough! No need for separate packages.